# Implementation of industry specific resources

Tags: c#, .net, resources, localization

We have a program that is used in one specific industry and has strings that are specific to that industry. We now have the situation where it can be used in another industry and we want to customise the strings for that industry without duplicating our code base.

The problem space appears very similar to localisation. Are we going to have a separate resource assembly for each industry? If so when would we choose which assembly to use, could we do this at install time or would it need to be at compile time?. How do we keep the separate resource assemblies synchronised, so that the same keys to messages appear in each one?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me re-phrase it: you have an industrial application which could be used in various industries and *the only* things that are different are resources (that is strings, layout, maybe images and sounds). The other code ***stays the same***.

In such case your problem is not just similar it is actually identical to Localization. And as such you can use [Satellite Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
Now, it is up to you if you want to package such created applications separately or distribute one application with both problem spaces.
The first seem more realistic scenario to me - you would need to decide on which .resx file to include at *compile* time (i.e. during project preparation you would overwrite existing resources with problem-space resources and then proceed with compilation, that should give you different flavors of your application; I would also modify their names in such case).
The latter would require you to manually instantiate `ResourceManager` at runtime to read from valid satellite assembly - it could be based on some configuration file. It means more work (you would need to actually modify your code) and you will end up distributing both flavors of your application at once, that is you won't have control over how your customers will use it. From the business perspective it could be a little dangerous.

---

**EDIT (Note to self: read whole question carefully)**

Somehow I managed to miss install time vs. compile time. I believe compile time is the answer because of the same reason I gave in config-driven switch section: you would package the resources and you won't have any control on how customers use it. Some clever guy would figure it out, that is for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having a properties file with key value pairs. Where you currently have industry specific strings, replace them with calls to the properties file. Obviously you would cache these strings in some container. I don't know the C# container - Java would use `java.util.Properties`.

```
aerospace.props:
INDUSTRY_NAME=aerospace
INDUSTRY_START_YEAR=1903


manufacturing.props:
INDUSTRY_NAME=manufacturing
INDUSTRY_START_YEAR=1600
```

Comment: this answer does not address the questions raised, and it is a .net specific question, not java. please remove this answer as it encourages others to not reply to a question that is already answered.

Comment: It does address the issue. You're looking for how to make your stuff be generic, and this solves it. I find it hard to believe you don't have a Map in C#?

Comment: if you don't know c#, please don't answer the question. You do not have the knowledge to comment on the following: .NET Resource assemblies, use at compile vs install time, synchronisation of .NET resource assemblies, each of which was mentioned in the question. If we wanted to code our own implementation we probably could using dictionaries, but in the vast extent of .NET an implementation already probably exists.

Comment: @Aran You're missing a fundamental point of my answer: **Your problem is not C# specific**. It is one that has plagued programmers since the days of Fortran and earlier. One solution that has stuck around because of how effective it is is a properties file. You are seriously overthinking this problem. The most elegant solution would be to, instead of referencing a constant String, using the result of a mapped get which is populated by a properties file. **Any implementation you go with will be a variation of this** if you want to fulfill your requirement of not duplicating the codebase.

Comment: I believe his problem is very .Net specific. There is no way to answer his question correctly without knowing .Net Resource Architecture. And I am afraid that you just have proved it.