# Can I switch between different sets of values for a form's label controls at runtime?

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, resources

I need to be able to change the text of a label depending on a setting (mostly labels, checkboxes too ... at least anything that has a label of some sort). This is needed because various customers using the application are using different terminology internally.
So, for example if I hardcode the value of a text label (accompanying a text box) to "Incident" that may not work for another customer as they want to use "Ticket" or "Service call".

I was thinking that I could use the localization feature in WinForms and create some sort of subculture (it is if you think about it) like en-us-cust1, en-us-cust2. The resources associated with them would contain different values for the labels' text whereever the term varies.

Another important thing is to be able to avoid having these resources compiled inside the assembly.

Note: I continued to search for a similar question and this one is identical [Implementation of industry specific resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852541/implementation-of-industry-specific-resources). I don't know yet if the answers to that one are satisfactory so any responses are still welcome.

Comment: You want to avoid to compile the values inside the assembly. Does it mean it's OK to have them compiled in a resource assembly? Or do you want to distrivute some source/text version of the "dictionary"?

Comment: It would be great to have the ability of modifying a text version of the mappings but I guess the best compromise is to have a satellite assembly for each customer and avoid the complications of letting them mess with the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above attempts completely answerd my question. So, I spent a couple of days (which I wanted to avoid) reading about localization in .Net and here's what I am going to do.

I wrote a tiny console application that allows me to create a custom culture based on an existing one and specify a new CultureName, CultureEnglishName, CultureNativeName and registers it on the Windows machine. This is going to be one of the setup steps of the application.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string operation = args[0];
    string newCultureName = args[1];
    string sourceCultureName = args[2];
    string newCultureDescriptiveName = args[3];

    try
    {
        if (operation == "Register")
        {
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder crib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(newCultureName, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
            crib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo(sourceCultureName));
            crib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo(sourceCultureName));
            crib.CultureEnglishName = newCultureDescriptiveName;
            crib.CultureNativeName = newCultureDescriptiveName;
            crib.Register();
        }
        else if (operation == "Unregister")
        {
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister(newCultureName);
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("The only accepted values are: Register; Unregister", "operation");
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I can create for example a culture named "en-CA-Company" by calling the console app like this:

```
consoleapp Register "en-CA-Company", "en-CA", "English (Canada) Company"
```

Setting the descriptive name was needed because the CultureEnglishName, CultureNativeName properties would have been left the same as in the source culture which would have created confusion when for example in Visual Studio you drop down the list of languages for a localized form and see two "English (Canada)" entries. I don't know which one property VS uses to display the language name so I guessed broadly going for both the English and the Native name.

Now, as my custom culture is registered on the machine I can see it in Visual Studio in the `Language` field of the form properties when I enable localization `Localizable = True`. 
[image]

When I select my new custom culture VS will create a separate resource file which will contain all the modifications I do to any labels ... while this culture is selected.

To get this specific resource file (and the strings in it) used I just have to:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA-Company");
```

somewhere when the application initializes.

Answer (score 1):

You can load label text from `Resource`

Have a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps create a `Dictionary` to store your "localization".

```
Dictionary<Control, string> myLocalization = new Dictionary<Control, string>();
```

Save it and read it something like this:

```
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
using (Stream streamout = File.Create(path)) serializer.Serialize(streamout, myLocalization);
using (Stream streamin = File.OpenRead(path)) myLocalization = (Dictionary<Control,string>)serializer.Deserialize(streamin);
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in myLocalization.Keys) ctrl.Text = myLocalization[ctrl];
```

You'll need:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
```

Comment: The use of a binary formatter implies that the program has some GUI to create and manage the dictionary, which is not likely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You'll need:

1.- Prepare your project by creating different localization files (I recommend you to take a look on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

2.- Set the culture at runtime:

```
// C#
// Sets the UI culture to French (France).
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

(code above extracted from the aforementioned source)

3.- Implement a helper (`static`) class that will be in charge of doing the hard work, whenever you need it, and at runtime, by accessing the child controls of your form (recursion suits very well here) and get an appropiate text for each of them. Of course, not all the controls on the `Form` must be user-language sensible, your code must decide, might be based on the type of control you are inspecting, to take a translated string from the resources or not.

4.- Put some kind of suffix in the names of the controls, as you mentioned in your description, so that you can use the name as a basis to decide the resource string to use.